# Org Mode Headers Won't Export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have headers at the top of the file that look like:

```
 #+TITLE: A Good Explanation
```

That looks like all the examples I can find browsing various web pages.

When I go to export in either LaTeX or HTML I see an error about

```
Wrong type arguement: listp, #("A Good Explanation" 0 24 (:parent (#0))
```

Yet headers for `LATEX_CLASS:` work as expected.  In fact the headers that don't work are grey and the ones that do, like LATEX_CLASS are colored reddish.

How do I put in headers for Title, Author, Email etc?

Comment: Which Emacs and org-mode version are you using?  Did you also reload org-mode or restarted Emacs?  Did you check with Emacs -Q?

Comment: It says Org-mode version 8.3.1.   Yes I have exited and restarted emacs many times.

Comment: After upgrading to org-mode 8.3.1, I started having problems exporting because a file was removed. Try using a slightly older version of org-mode or newer version to see if problem disappears.